# Java ParseException Unparseable date when date string is UTC+13:00 timezone

Tags: java

I am getting weird error which I can't get around easily.
This is my code

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[S][SS][SSS][SSSS][SSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSSS]X");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date issued = df.parse(this.dateAndTimeOfIssue);
```

I am getting exception
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-02-13T00:00:51.045+13:00"

Does anyone knows what is causing error?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead justv use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Date.from( 
    OffsetDateTime
    .parse( "2018-02-13T00:00:51.045+13:00" )
    .toInstant() 
)
```

## Details

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Avoid `Date`/`Calendar`.

For a date with time of day as seen with a particular offset, use `OffsetDateTime` class.

Your input text complies with the standard ISO 8601 format used by default in the *java.time* classes. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-02-13T00:00:51.045+13:00" )
```

If you must use the legacy classes to interoperate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can convert to and fro. Use the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = Date.from( myOffsetDateTime.toInstant() ) ;
```

All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more. And see the tutorial provided by Oracle Corp free of cost.

Comment: This is legacy code and there is Date class everywhere. It needs massive refactoring. Its confusing that code works for +1,+2,+3... but not for 13 -.- Java is a mess when it comes to datetime. There is like 6 different types of date :) Thank you for no. 7 date representation

Comment: @SlobodanT Just convert back and forth. See my edits.

Comment: @SlobodanT Actually, the entire information technology industry has been frightfully ignorant of proper date-time handling. The legacy classes in the early versions of Java were donated by IBM & Taligent. Despite those big names, the classes were written by people who clearly did not understand the subtleties and complexities of date-time handling. The first competent date-time library I know of was *Joda-Time*, whose creator went on to lead the *java.time* JSR 310 effort. So, the rule is simple: Write all your new code in *java.time* classes, converting as needed for old code.

Comment: Yeah I found the way.Not the pretty one.Convert OffsetDateTime to LocalDateTime then to Date via Instant. The main problem is that model classes and business logic involved deal with Date.And if I change it I will get a lot of errors.It works for now. Thanks!!!

Comment: Don’t use LocalDateTime for this.  You will corrupt your data.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `SimpleDateFormat` does not support the optional sections - that is, the enclosure of parts of the format in `[ ]` characters.  You need to either

- abandon the use of the optional sections,
- write your own `DateFormat` implementation,
- switch to the more modern classes in the `java.time` package.

The third option is usually the best - the `java.time` package has been around for many years now, and the `DateTimeFormatter` class does indeed support the `[ ]` notation.  But if you have to deal with legacy date and time classes, you might be best to write your own `DateFormat`.